# What's the advantage of bitpay over coinbase for a merchant solution?

Tags: coinbase.com, bitpay, merchant-services

I'm trying to figure out why a merchant would ever choose bitpay over coinbase as an integration solution.  It seems they offer very similar services (accept bitcoin payments, exchange for dollars automatically daily and deposit into your bank account), yet BitPay charges 1% and Coinbase nothing.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think CoinBase only serves US merchants, Bitpay serves international merchants.

Comment: You should correct this: Bitpay does not charge for transactions.

Comment: @philosodad, they certainly did at the time I asked this.  If they have changed their policy, please provide a link to that info

Comment: @RentFree https://bitpay.com/pricing "Unlimited payment processing, free forever" -- you're right of course, a more accurate thing for me to say would be "Bitpay no longer charges for transactions"

Comment: OK, do you know when the change was made?

Answer (score 2):

I would encourage you to look at the customer reviews of each service.  BitPay is definitely a stronger and more reliable platform, and is fully "on-blockchain" and compatible with all of the bitcoin wallets.  For a low-volume use case, like a few orders per day, probably either service will work.  For higher volumes, BitPay is more business-grade, with features like Quickbooks import.